# Kotlin print() method dosen't work in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I'm trying to debug android native code (kotlin) for flutter using the print().

The problem I'm facing is that it doesn't print in the console when I run the app.

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val channel = "com.example.pomo_app/mychannel"

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channel)  
          .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                    when (call.method) {
                        "getAllRingtones" -> {
                            // this doesn't print to console
                            print("Native code works")
                          
                        }
```

Comment: Please, Provide code for more understand your problem

Comment: have you try `log()` from dart library `dart:developer` ?

Comment: @Poran there you go. what I was trying to do is to print something from the MainActivity.kt whenever flutter calls the getAllRingtones function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `Log.d("TAG", "your log message")` for Android native logs.

Kotlin `print()` and `println()` methods won't work.

Bit if you want to log some native ios code, you can use `print()` and `println()` methods in Swift

Comment: I have tried Log.println() before and it didn't work, but Log.d() worked just fine.
thanks, man.  

Comment: You are welcome) Log.println() is a low-level logging call and better to use Log.d(), Log.e(), Log.i() and other specific methods. @zaynOm